# Creating a reverse proxy with NGINX. What am I missing?

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

## Help Debugging

I have been trying to create a reverse proxy with NGINX. For now I'm just trying to get it to redirect traffic on my local network. I think I'm close, but I'm stuck. Any advice is appreciated!

The expected behavior is that a request to `http://api.dev.tagnoo.com` routes traffic to one container, while `http://app.dev.tagnoo.com` routes traffic to another.

The actual behavior is that I can't access anything despite my containers running and Nginx seeming to be working. I have no idea how to debug this.

### Recreating My Pain

I spin up containers with the following commands:

`docker-compose pull --include-deps $@`

`docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans --build $@`

My docker-compose.yaml file looks like this

```
services:
  lb:
    image: nginx:1.19.7-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./src/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./src/fullchain.pem:/etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem
      - ./src/privkey.pem:/etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - api.dev.tagnoo.com
          - app.dev.tagnoo.com
          - dev.tagnoo.com

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.3-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  api: &api
    image: 410ventures/tagnoo-api:latest
    environment: &api_environment
      TEST_VAR: 'test123'
      VERSION: development
      WATCH: 1
  
  api-test:
    <<: *api
    command: ["true"]
    environment:
      <<: *api_environment
      TAGNOO_API_URL: http://localhost
      POSTGRES_URL: pg://postgres:postgres@postgres/tagnooTest
      REDIS_KEY_PREFIX: 'api-test:'

  api-app-test:
    <<: *api
    command: ["true"]
    environment:
      <<: *api_environment
      TAGNOO_API_URL: http://api-app-test
      POSTGRES_URL: pg://postgres:postgres@postgres/tagnooAppTest
      WATCH: 1

  app: &app
    image: 410ventures/tagnoo-app:latest
    environment: &app_environment
      VERSION: development
      WATCH: 1
  
  app-build:
    <<: *app
    command: ["true"]

  app-livereload:
    <<: *app
    command: ["true"]

  app-test:
    <<: *app
    command: ["true"]
    environment:
      <<: *app_environment
      TAGNOO_APP_URL: http://localhost
      TAGNOO_API_URL: http://api-app-test

volumes:
  pg-data:
```

This works as expected:
[container info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGxwp.png)

My `nginx.conf` file looks like this

```
events {}

http {   server_tokens off;

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    '' close;
    default upgrade;   }

  proxy_http_version 1.1;   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;   proxy_set_header Host $host;   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem;   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem;

  proxy_read_timeout 24h;

  # proxy_pass directives are passed hosts via a $proxy_pass_host variable to   # allow nginx to start up before the hosts are actually available. Putting the   # hosts directly in the proxy_pass directive will fail start up unless all   # hosts are available. A resolver is required to use variables in proxy_pass   # directives, so use the docker internal DNS IP here.   resolver 127.0.0.11;

  server {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;   }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name app.dev.tagnoo.com;

    location /livereload {
      set $proxy_pass_host app-livereload:35729;
      proxy_pass http://$proxy_pass_host;
    }

    location / {
      set $proxy_pass_host app;
      proxy_pass http://$proxy_pass_host;
    }   }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.dev.tagnoo.com;

    location / {
      set $proxy_pass_host api;
      proxy_pass http://$proxy_pass_host;
    }   } }
```

I have `privkey.pem` and `fullchain.pem` files in my root directory. I just self-signed them using `openssl` but I assume that should still work for my local network if I ignore ssl.

### What I've tried

I've tried accessing the containers (to no avail) through:

- http://api.dev.tagnoo.com
- https://api.dev.tagnoo.com/healthz (an endpoint I use to test connection)
- https://api.dev.tagnoo.com
- localhost:80
- 0.0.0.0:80

Here are the logs for the responses I get (in no particular order)
[docker compose logs for lb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRFIr.png)

I haven't set up any DNS records for my domain, `tagnoo.com`, but I don't think that should matter because this is just a local environment at the moment. But I'm not sure if that's true.

I can't find more information about debugging NGINX at this point.

### Summary

I'm mainly concerned that my NGINX config file is not doing what it should. I'm also not sure if my docker-compose file is set up correctly for the reverse-proxy.

My containers are running, but the reverse proxy to them is broken somehow. Requests fail with `302` or `301 getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.dev.tagnoo.com` whenever I attempt to access.

Here are some questions I have on the matter:

- Is there anything else I need to do to setup this reverse proxy? Am I missing a step?
- Are the `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` files the reason NGINX is failing? If so - how do I create these?
- Is docker-compose configured correctly?
- How can I debug this further?

Any advice/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: does anything work if you use https? or localhost:443?

Comment: No, it will return 'Error: SSL Certificate self-signed' when I try https. When I disable ssl certificate verification it again says `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Comment: Have you installed the certificate on the host machine?

Comment: I've solved this. Thank you @richardsefton for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had not yet setup A and AAAA records to resolve the *.dev subdomain to localhost. I added those and created a valid (not self-signed) certificate for the host machine.